# docpad-plugin-tags How to display tags on a specific page?

Tags: plugins, tags, docpad

docpad-plugin-tags

This all tags:

```
<ul><% for file in @getFilesAtPath('tags/').toJSON(): %>
  <li>
    <a href="<%= file.url %>"><%= file.title %></a>
  </li>
<% end %></ul>
```

How to display tags on a specific page?

Answer (score 0):

The tag array is a property of the document object rather than the file object. Both the file object and the document object contain a "URL" and "title" property. So it's better to use the document collection rather than the file collection. Something like this:

```
<ul><% for doc in @getCollection('documents').findAllLive({relativeOutDirPath: 'tags'}).toJSON(): %>
  <li>
    <a href="<%= doc.url %>"><%= doc.title %> tags: <%=doc.tags%></a>
  </li>
<% end %></ul>
```

More info on the docpad [meta data page](http://docpad.org/docs/meta-data) and the [template data page](http://docpad.org/docs/template-data)